# Alignment issue : Safari on MacBook Showing bootstrap buttons on extreme right of the screen

Tags: html, css, macos, button, safari

I just checked one of my websites on safari. It dislocates the buttons to the extreme right of the screen (between 100-200%) enabling horizontal scroll unnecessarily while it works properly on Google Chrome. Here is the code for reference.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

        <style>
                body {
                    background: linear-gradient(-15deg, #e77817 0%, #fff 20%, #fff 80%, #152d65 95%);
                }


            ::-webkit-scrollbar{
                width: 6px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
                background: #152d65;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
            ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
                background: #e77817;
            }

            #Logo{
                    width:27%;              
                    }                   
            h3{
                font-size:25px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-family:'ElMessiri Regular', sans-serif;
                }
            
            .poly {
                margin-right: 2%;
                margin-top: 1%;
                width: 20%;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-family: "ElMessiri Regular";
            }

            
            #List {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
            }
            #plastic {
                background: #152d65;
            }
            #plastic:hover {
                color: #e77817;
            }
            #cares {
                background: #009534;
            }
            #cares:hover {
                color: #FFED00;
            }
            #medical {
                background: #e77817;
            }
            #medical:hover {
                color: #152d65;
            }
            
        </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <center>
        <div id="Logo"> 
            <img src="Images/Logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="aaaaaaa">    
        </div>      
        <div id="Company_Name">     
        <h3> ABC Pvt Ltd </h3>      
        </div>
        <br>        
        <div id="List" class="col-lg-12 container" style="height: 100%; width: 100%:">
            <a class="col-lg-2 poly btn"  id="plastic" href="aaa.html"><div>AAA</div></a>
            <a class="col-lg-2 poly btn"  id="cares" href="bbb.html"><div>BBB</div></a>
            <a class="col-lg-2 poly btn" id ="medical" href="ccc.html"><div>CCC</div></a>
            
        </div>
        </center>
```

The error has only found on Safari Browser on MacOS. It works fine on iPhones. Only the buttons get dislocated to extreme right of the screen while all other things remain in their specified location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `display: flex` and `col-lg-*` from the code and tried running it and it started working well on Safari for MacBook as well Chrome.